# How to user the prefix route name

Tags: laravel, routes, autoprefixer

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'role:admin'])->name('admin.')->prefix('admin')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/role', [RoleController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
});
```

I want to user this route name. How I can?

```
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{ url('admin/role') }}" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Roles</p>
                </a>
              </li>
```

user as url and it's working but I want to user the route name

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `url()` method ,use `route()`.Here `admin`  refers to `->name('admin.')` and `index` refers to `->name('index')`

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.index') }}" class="nav-link">
```

Ref: [URLs For Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes)

route method parameters

```
/**
     * Generate the URL to a named route.
     *
     * @param  array|string  $name
     * @param  mixed  $parameters
     * @param  bool  $absolute
     * @return string
     */
    function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
    {
        return app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
    }
```

Comment: I have already tried but thats not working

Comment: @TutulHosen it should work . what error are you getting

Answer (score 0):

You can use route() function to get url based on its name. Keep in mind that the prefix wont change the name defined in route, so in your case the name will be "index", not "admin.index"

```
<a href="{{ route('index') }}" class="nav-link">
```

But it will be better if you use a more detailed route name to prevent overlapped of route name, Example :

```
// no need to use name() in grouping level
Route::middleware(['auth', 'role:admin'])->prefix('admin')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/role', [RoleController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.index'); // set the complete name here
});
```

so you will be able to call them with this :

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.index') }}" class="nav-link">
```

Comment: Route::middleware(['auth', 'role:admin'])->prefix('admin')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/role', [RoleController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
});
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{ route('admin.role.index') }}" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Roles</p>
                </a>
              </li>

Comment: Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [admin.role.index] not defined. (View: C:\Users\PC_37\Desktop\practice_session\auth\resources\views\admin\layout\sidebar.blade.php)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/role
This error has been created

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin'], function(){
```

Route::resource('routename', ExampleController::class);
});